# How to I detrmine Which Version of Restlet API I am using?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, restlet

I am using a java restlet client server based architecture.

**How to I detrmine Which Version of Restlet API I am using ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following code:

```
import org.restlet.engine.Engine;
(...)
System.out.println("version = "+Engine.VERSION);
```

If you have access to the source code, you can have a look within the class `Engine`:

```
public class Engine {
    (...)

    /** Major version number. */
    public static final String MAJOR_NUMBER = "2";

    /** Minor version number. */
    public static final String MINOR_NUMBER = "3";

    /** Release number. */
    public static final String RELEASE_NUMBER = ".1";

    (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry